# ReactJS - Can't build, minify error when using "Regex: named capturing groups"

Tags: reactjs

This is my regex:

```
let validCharacter = new RegExp(
    /[\s\'\"\-\:\,\!\;\(\)\?\.a-zA-Z0-9àáãạảăắằẳẵặâấầẩẫậèéẹẻẽêềếểễệđìíĩỉịòóõọỏôốồổỗộơớờởỡợùúũụủưứừửữựỳỵỷỹýÀÁÃẠẢĂẮẰẲẴẶÂẤẦẨẪẬÈÉẸẺẼÊỀẾỂỄỆĐÌÍĨỈỊÒÓÕỌỎÔỐỒỔỖỘƠỚỜỞỠỢÙÚŨỤỦƯỨỪỬỮỰỲỴỶỸÝ]+|(?<invalid>.)/,
    'gi'
  );
```

This `?<invalid>` cause error: **Failed to minify the code** when build.

Below is my entire webpack config content:

```
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs"),
    path = require("path"),
    webpack = require("webpack"),
    resolve = require("resolve"),
    PnpWebpackPlugin = require("pnp-webpack-plugin"),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
    InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin"),
    TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin"),
    MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin"),
    OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin"),
    ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin"),
    InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin"),
    WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require("workbox-webpack-plugin"),
    ModuleScopePlugin = require("react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin"),
    getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require("react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent"),
    paths = require("./paths"),
    getClientEnvironment = require("./env"),
    ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin"),
    ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt"),
    typescriptFormatter = require("react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter"),
    publicPath = paths.servedPath,
    shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = "./" === publicPath,
    shouldUseSourceMap = "false" !== process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP,
    shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = "false" !== process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK,
    publicUrl = publicPath.slice(0, -1),
    env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);
if ('"production"' !== env.stringified["process.env"].NODE_ENV) throw Error("Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.");
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig),
    cssRegex = /\.css$/,
    cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/,
    sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/,
    getStyleLoaders = (e, s) => {
        const t = [{
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: Object.assign({}, shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? {
                publicPath: "../../"
            } : void 0)
        }, {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
            options: e
        }];
        s && t.push({
            loader: require.resolve(s),
            options: {
                sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
            }
        });
        return t
    };
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    bail: !0,
    devtool: !!shouldUseSourceMap && "source-map",
    entry: [paths.appIndexJs],
    output: {
        path: paths.appBuild,
        filename: "static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js",
        chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js",
        publicPath: publicPath,
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: e => path.relative(paths.appSrc, e.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
                parse: {
                    ecma: 8
                },
                compress: {
                    ecma: 5,
                    warnings: !1,
                    comparisons: !1,
                    inline: 2
                },
                mangle: {
                    safari10: !0
                },
                output: {
                    ecma: 5,
                    comments: !1,
                    ascii_only: !0
                }
            },
            parallel: !0,
            cache: !0,
            sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
        })],
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            name: !1
        },
        runtimeChunk: !0
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ["node_modules"].concat(process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)),
        extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions.map(e => `.${e}`).filter(e => useTypeScript || !e.includes("ts")),
        alias: {
            "react-native": "react-native-web"
        },
        plugins: [PnpWebpackPlugin, new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson])]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        plugins: [PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module)]
    },
    module: {
        strictExportPresence: !0,
        rules: [{
            parser: {
                requireEnsure: !1
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
            enforce: "pre",
            use: [{
                options: {
                    formatter: require.resolve("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter"),
                    eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint")
                },
                loader: require.resolve("eslint-loader")
            }],
            include: paths.appSrc
        }, {
            oneOf: [{
                test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
                options: {
                    limit: 1e4,
                    name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                include: paths.appSrc,
                loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
                options: {
                    customize: require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides"),
                    plugins: [
                        [require.resolve("babel-plugin-named-asset-import"), {
                            loaderMap: {
                                svg: {
                                    ReactComponent: "@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]"
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    ],
                    cacheDirectory: !0,
                    cacheCompression: !0,
                    compact: !0
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
                exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
                loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
                options: {
                    babelrc: !1,
                    configFile: !1,
                    compact: !1,
                    presets: [
                        [require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app/dependencies"), {
                            helpers: !0
                        }]
                    ],
                    cacheDirectory: !0,
                    cacheCompression: !0,
                    sourceMaps: !1
                }
            }, {
                test: cssRegex,
                exclude: cssModuleRegex,
                loader: getStyleLoaders({
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
                }),
                sideEffects: !0
            }, {
                test: cssModuleRegex,
                loader: getStyleLoaders({
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                    modules: !0,
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
                })
            }, {
                test: sassRegex,
                exclude: sassModuleRegex,
                loader: getStyleLoaders({
                    importLoaders: 2,
                    sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
                }, "sass-loader"),
                sideEffects: !0
            }, {
                test: sassModuleRegex,
                loader: getStyleLoaders({
                    importLoaders: 2,
                    sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                    modules: !0,
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
                }, "sass-loader")
            }, {
                loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
                exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
                options: {
                    name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: !0,
        template: paths.appHtml,
        minify: {
            removeComments: !0,
            collapseWhitespace: !0,
            removeRedundantAttributes: !0,
            useShortDoctype: !0,
            removeEmptyAttributes: !0,
            removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: !0,
            keepClosingSlash: !0,
            minifyJS: !0,
            minifyCSS: !0,
            minifyURLs: !0
        },
        isProductionMode: "production" === process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_CONFIG
    }), shouldInlineRuntimeChunk && new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime~.+[.]js/]), new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw), new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath), new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified), new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
        chunkFilename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css"
    }), new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: "asset-manifest.json",
        publicPath: publicPath
    }), new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/), new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
        clientsClaim: !0,
        exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
        importWorkboxFrom: "cdn",
        navigateFallback: publicUrl + "/index.html",
        navigateFallbackBlacklist: [RegExp("^/_"), RegExp("/[^/]+\\.[^/]+$")]
    }), fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig) && new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
        typescript: resolve.sync("typescript", {
            basedir: paths.appNodeModules
        }),
        async: !1,
        checkSyntacticErrors: !0,
        tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
        compilerOptions: {
            module: "esnext",
            moduleResolution: "node",
            resolveJsonModule: !0,
            isolatedModules: !0,
            noEmit: !0,
            jsx: "preserve"
        },
        reportFiles: ["**", "!**/*.json", "!**/__tests__/**", "!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*", "!src/setupProxy.js", "!src/setupTests.*"],
        watch: paths.appSrc,
        silent: !0,
        formatter: typescriptFormatter
    })].filter(Boolean),
    node: {
        dgram: "empty",
        fs: "empty",
        net: "empty",
        tls: "empty",
        child_process: "empty"
    },
    performance: !1
};
```

When I remove `?<invalid>` from the regex my project is build successfully.
Anyone got some idea about this case?

Thanks for you help!

Sorry I have to write this because "*It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.*"

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let validCharacter = new RegExp(
    /[\s\'\"\-\:\,\!\;\(\)\?\.a-zA-\ ... ]+|(\?<invalid>.)/,
    'gi'
  );
```

You need to escape the ? mark at the beginning of a group. A question mark means the previous character is optional but in in this case there is no previous character so the regex throws a syntax error.

A good way to troubleshoot code like this is to copy-paste it into your browser console and play with it until it compiles and does what you want.